# Command line tools download in Xcode disappeared after Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, eclipse, gcc, osx-mavericks

After having installed Mavericks I got this problem on a code that compiled without problems before.

xcode-select --install triggers the installation without any strange problems,

yet when I try to build something with Eclipse it gives me

```
"Include path not found (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include)"
```

Infact in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/ there's no llvm-gcc-4.2.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

On my system in terminal:

`/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`
produces:
`/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`

`/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`
is linked to :
`/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`

Also
`$ which llvm-gcc`
produces:
`/usr/bin/llvm-gcc`
and
`/usr/bin/llvm-gcc` is linked to `/usr/bin/clang`

Note that Apple no longer provides llvm-gcc as an option in Xcode so perhaps it is no longer supplied as a command-line tool.

Comment: On mine: $ which llvm-gcc-4.2 gives nothing!

Comment: It could be that is a holdover from a previous install. Try `which llvm-gcc` or perhaps switch to `clang`.

Comment: Change the path in Eclipse to `/usr/bin/llvm-gcc`.

Comment: It does not let me change the path, the "edit" button is gray.
IT should be the one in Project settings -> C/C++ general -> Preprocessor including.. -> Entries -> language panel -> GNU C++ -> GCC compiler settings MinGW isn't it? 

EDIT:
The path in "Include path not found (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include)"
suggests me that llvm-gcc shall be a folder, but the one I have in /usr/bin is not a folder. 

I'm quite confused it all worked before sob sob

Comment: Sorry, I do not use "Eclipse". The path that is in Eclipse points inside an Xcode app, that is not the way Apple does this no so that really needs to be changed. See if there is an option to change the compiler to `clang`, that really is the way forward. Perhaps open a new question asking how to use gcc in Eclipse on OSX 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the command line tools as well after upgrading to Mavericks, despite having updated Xcode, and I am quite sure I also installed the command line tools. Still, you can add them "by hand" downloading from apple site. I am not sure if it is any sort of bug of such, but anyway, I recommend you to download the latest Mavericks' Command Line Tools (late October) [on Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (needs free registration)

Comment: I installed them from the dev site as you suggested but unfortunately it keeps telling me that llvm-gcc-4.2 is not there :\